# How to implement This MP problem in ECLIPSE CLP or Prolog?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I want to implement this Summations as Objective and Constraints(1-6)
Could anyone help me that how I can Implement them?

OBJ: Min ∑(i=1..N)∑(j=1..N) Cij * ∑(k=1..K)Xijk

constraint :
              ∑(k=1..K) Yik=1 (for all i in N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is specific to ECLiPSe (it uses loops, array and array slice notation, which are not part of standard Prolog).

I assume that `N` and `K` (and presumably `C`) are given, and your matrices are declared as

```
dim(C, [N,N]),
dim(X, [N,N,K]),
dim(Y, [N,K]),
```

You can then set up the constraints in a loop:

> constraint : ∑(k=1..K) Yik=1 (for all i in N)

```
( for(I,1,N), param(Y) do
    sum(Y[I,*]) $= 1
),
```

Note that the notation `sum(Y[I,*])` here is a shorthand for `sum([Y[I,1],Y[I,2],...,Y[I,K]])` when `K` is the size of this array dimension.

For your objective, because of the nested sum, an auxiliary loop/list is still necessary:

> OBJ: Min ∑(i=1..N)∑(j=1..N) Cij * ∑(k=1..K)Xijk

```
( multifor([I,J],1,N), foreach(Term,Terms), param(C,X) do
    Term = (C[I,J] * sum(X[I,J,*]))
),
Objective = sum(Terms),
...
```

You then have to pass this objective expression to the solver -- the details depend on which solver you use (e.g. eplex, ic).

Comment: jschimpf ,Very thanks, But why you use * while k is on of indices? 
And how is for Min. I can not see in answer?