# How to implement these Sigma notations in ECLIPSE-CLP or Prolog

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

Is it possible for someone to tell me how to implement these sigmas in ECLiPSe-CLP or Prolog or at least give me guidance on how to implement and solve them.

[image]

Comment: This question is very similar to the one I answered earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778381/how-to-implement-this-mp-problem-in-eclipse-clp-or-prolog, you should be able to work from there.

Comment: Yes, But I couldnt solve this. Unfortunately there isn't any sample for this. If u help me I am sure that it will a good reference for others that looking such that